# combo boxes in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a table of Events, Contacts and Event Participants.  The simplified data structure is:

### tblContacts

- CT_ID (Primary Key, Int)
- CT_FirstName (nvarchar(20)
- CT_Surame (nvarchar(20))

### tblEvents

- EV_ID (Primary Key, Int)
- EV_EventName (nvarchar(20))

### tblEventParticipants

- EVPT_ID (Primary Key, Int)
- EVPT_EV_ID (Int, links to Event)
- EVPT_CT_ID (Int, links to Contact)

I want to be able to display the NAMES of the participants in the datagridview.

Using a combobox column type is not appropriate due to speed as there are 50,000 contacts in the database and there may be over 1,000 participants in any one event.

I need to be able to add to, delete from and edit existing rows in the datagridview.

Does anyone have an efficient way of being able to do this please?

Comment: You want an end user to have to wade through 50k contacts in a drop down list?

Comment: crazy if you want to add 50k+ items to a single drop down box....

Comment: Use Master-Detail type layout would be one way.  All the Participants in one DGV, allow the user to filter them various way to make it easy to find the one they want.  Same for the Events list.  Then, maybe double clicking a row adds that Participant to a 3rd DGV which is the EventParticpant table